# Scale image to full page, keeping aspect ratio

Tags: graphics, scaling

I have an image and want to scale it to the full page size. I know, I can use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}` to scale an image to the full page width (or `\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[height=\pagewidth]{...}}` in case the image needs to be turned 90 degrees). But the problem is that my images then use more space than the height of the page.

I have also tried to do `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]` and actually that also worked, but this opens two problems:

1. I have to guess for each image whether the height or the width will be the limiting factor and
2. there is no more space for the image caption. This means, I get an overfull box unless I reduce the height manually, but I have to guess the factor for each image.

What I'd really appreciate is to say that I want such an image to be scaled as much as possible, keeping the aspect ratio but small enough that the caption also fits into the page. Is there a good way to achieve this?

I am using the `scrbook` class, should that make any difference.

Comment: See my edit yo avoid caption room, I have missed on the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape,graphicx,ifthen,calc}

\newsavebox{\image}
\newlength{\MyLgth}

\def\CaptionRoom{30pt} % Empirically set

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DivideLengths}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\number\numexpr\number\dimexpr#1\relax*65536/\number\dimexpr#2\relax\relax sp\relax
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\SetMyLght}[1]{%
    \sbox{\image}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}%
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\ht\image>\textheight}}{%
        \setlength{\MyLgth}{%
        \DivideLengths{\textheight-\CaptionRoom}{\ht\image}\linewidth}%
    }{%
        \setlength{\MyLgth}{\linewidth}%
    }%
}


\newcommand{\MyImage}[2][]{%
\sbox{\image}{\includegraphics{#2}}%
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\wd\image>\ht\image}}{%
\begin{landscape}%
    \SetMyLght{#2}%
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \hfill\includegraphics[width=\MyLgth]{#2}\hfill\strut%
    \caption{#1}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}{%
    \SetMyLght{#2}%
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \hfill\includegraphics[width=\MyLgth]{#2}\hfill\strut%
    \caption{#1}
    \end{figure}
}
}

\begin{document}

\MyImage[Why science teachers should not be given playground duty.]{sc-teacher}%

\MyImage[The Monkey selfie.]{monkey-selfie}

\end{document}
```